# How to create columns from a text file containing strings with spaces?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to read a file in pyspark and create a dataframe out of it. It is a tsv file with the values in the form of:

```
2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z "strings with space" "strings with space" ECDHE THRGH
```

I tried to create row objects and converting those to dataframe. But I am stuck with how to split the data and create columns. Data contains strings with spaces.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import re

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Task1") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

# Load a text file and convert each line to a Row.
lines = sc.textFile("file.tsv")
#parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(" ")) -- Tried this but it doesn't give correct output as there are spaces in strings.
values = lines.map(lambda p: Row(value=re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"', str(p))[0].replace(" ","")))
```

The ideal results would be a dataframe as below :

```
Timestamp                          val1              val2      
 val3       val4
2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z strings with space strings with space ECDHE THRGH
```

Comment: `spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv("path to file")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't give the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load any seperated file(asv) into spark, you just need to mention the seperator as well.

```
df = spark.read.load("examples/src/main/resources/sample.txt",
                 format="csv", sep=" ", inferSchema="true", header="true")
```

in the above line use space in **sep** attribute.

**Edited:**

Try below for changing column names in case if file don't have any header. Also mark **header="false"**

```
df = spark.read.load("examples/src/main/resources/sample.txt",
                 format="csv", sep=" ", inferSchema="true", header="false").toDF("id","name", "salary")
```

Comment: Seems to be working. Thanks. How can I add header  in data while reading file? I don't have header in my file.

Comment: Edited my answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

Here is my tsv file but actually separated with spaces.

```
timestamp col1 col2 col3 col4
2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z "strings with space" "strings with space" ECDHE THRGH
2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z "strings with space" "strings with space" ECDHE THRGH
2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z "strings with space" "strings with space" ECDHE THRGH
2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z "strings with space" "strings with space" ECDHE THRGH
2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z "strings with space" "strings with space" ECDHE THRGH
```

With my below code,

```
df = spark.read.option("delimiter", " ").option("header", "true").csv("path/to/tsv")
df.show(7, False)
```

the result is shown below.

```
+---------------------------+------------------+------------------+-----+-----+
|timestamp                  |col1              |col2              |col3 |col4 |
+---------------------------+------------------+------------------+-----+-----+
|2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z|strings with space|strings with space|ECDHE|THRGH|
|2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z|strings with space|strings with space|ECDHE|THRGH|
|2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z|strings with space|strings with space|ECDHE|THRGH|
|2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z|strings with space|strings with space|ECDHE|THRGH|
|2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z|strings with space|strings with space|ECDHE|THRGH|
|2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z|strings with space|strings with space|ECDHE|THRGH|
|2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z|strings with space|strings with space|ECDHE|THRGH|
+---------------------------+------------------+------------------+-----+-----+
```

It looks working well.

Comment: Actually I don't have tabs between fields. All fields are separated by spaces itself. Plus the "strings with space" has space.

Comment: I change the header option to `df = spark.read.option("delimiter", " ")` and it worked. I don't know why.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be working. How can I add header to this dataframe here itself. Is there any option which I can write in the same statement that you gave.

Comment: I add the option for header true when I load the file to the dataframe if you have a header on the top of the file.

Comment: or if you dont have the header, then try to add the option at last such as .toDF("col1","col2","col3")

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot.